# Automatic sorting by id, not alphabetically

Tags: php, mysql

A few days ago I created a table where there are categories for blog posts. They were sorted by the id of the item in the table (without the need to enter any data such as ORDER BY). Today I created an identical table and the category is sorted alphabetically. How to sort them automatically by id? Please help me, I have no idea why this happened.
EDIT: My table structure:

```
1   id Primary   int(11)   No   None   AUTO_INCREMENT
2   name Index   varchar(255)   utf8_general_ci   No   None
```

Comment: could you show us your table structure?

Comment: No they weren't. Rows in RDBMS tables represent unordered sets. The only way of establishing an order is with an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: In the sql tab of the table I had such a record: SELECT * FROM `tags` WHERE 1. Sorted by id.

Comment: What does WHERE 1 actually mean?

Comment: @waanofii.tech I edit my question, added table structure

Answer (score 4):

It seems it was a plain coincidence you saw the rows in the order you wanted, but that's not assured.

The rows in a database table do not have inherent ordering. Every time you retrieve the data from the table you need to specify the order you want by adding the `ORDER BY` clause. If you don't add it, then you'll receive the rows in any order. Even more, this order may change over time without notice.

Comment: So what do I have to add to the sorting for id? ORDER BY...

Comment: This is going to be all right?  ORDER BY `id` ASC?

Comment: @hello Yes, you can do `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id`.